# How can I change the color of headings within a div that has a specific css property and value

Tags: css

The client requested that all the content headings (h1, h2, h3, etc.) should be changed to black (#0a0a0a).

Only problem now, is that there are a lot of containers with a black background, which now also contains black headings (making them "invisible").

How can I target these headings (the ones located within divs with background-color=#0a0a0a) in specific? I have tried the following already, which doesn't work:

`.avia-section [style=background-color:#0a0a0a] h3 {color:#fff}`

`.avia-section [style*=background-color:#0a0a0a] h3 {color:#fff}`

`.avia-section [*=background-color:#0a0a0a] h3 {color:#fff}`

`div [style=background-color:#0a0a0a] h3 {color:#fff}`

`div [class=avia-section] [style=background-color:#0a0a0a] h3 {color:#fff}`

An example of one of these div's css, is as follows:

`.avia-section.av-dw0yqh-ce5ce087d66e604a42c59fdb6c869549 { background-color: #0a0a0a; background-image: url(unset); }`

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: set all tag color globally then, yon can get those containers class and override their h tag as you wish

Comment: _"Kindly view [url]"_ - kindly provide a proper [mre] of your issue directly inside the question. As for reasons why, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1427878

Comment: The issue here, is that the exact same class is used for all containers (parent divs) located within the content/main area, i.e. the css for one of the divs/containers, is as follows: .avia-section.av-dw0yqh-ce5ce087d66e604a42c59fdb6c869549 { background-color: #0a0a0a; background-image: url(unset); }. Targeting these divs' headings seems to be impossible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global style for `h3` then use `[style*="background-color:#0a0a0a"]` for create a condition like:

```css
h3{
  color:black;
}
div[style*="background-color:#0a0a0a"] h3{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
<div style="background-color:#0a0a0a">
  <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The issue is that it's not an inline style. You will notice, that the css for one of the divs (of which the heading color has to be targeted/changed), is as follows:
.avia-section.av-dw0yqh-ce5ce087d66e604a42c59fdb6c869549 { background-color: #0a0a0a; background-image: url(unset); }

That is why I tried .avia-section [style=background-color:#0a0a0a] h3 {color:#fff} which didn't work

Comment: So simple check if has this class .avia-section.av-dw0yqh-ce5ce087d66e604a42c59fdb6c869549 right?

Comment: I wish it was; the part after .avia-section changes for each div, so that its class is unique. In example, the one div/container has a class in the css file of .avia-section.av-dw0yqh-ce5ce087d66e604a42c59fdb6c869549 while the other is .avia-section.av-kvqg5xhy-8c26bb39b69d4b44ed06e7362a693729.

I cannot target all these divs' heading's color, as each one's background color differs.

In short, all I am trying to do, is change the heading color to white (#fff) when the background color of the surrounding div is black (more specific #0a0a0a).